# Make a leaderboard ranking from table in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with names and their scores and I'd like to insert into the table the rank according to the score. My database looks a bit like this:
[phpmyadmin database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIHKl.png)

I would like to make it so when the score is higher than a rank the ranks change in the database. So if there were a player 1 with 500 points and a player 2 with 1500 points, the code would insert the rank into the rank column corresponding with the player's name.
Like this:

| Rank | Name | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Player2 | 1500 |
| 2 | Player1 | 500 |

Answer (score 0):

Don't store the RANK in the database calculate it on the fly when you read the data using the RANK() function.

```
SELECT
    Player,
    Score,
    RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Score DESC) AS 'RANK'
FROM
    PlayerScore
ORDER BY
    Score DESC
```

If you can have tied scores you can use DENSE_RANK(). This would give you ranks of 1,2,2,3.  RANK would just give you 1,2,2,4